# Retrofit GET with undeclared JSON Body

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to submit a @Body of JSON to a Retrofit-declared interface method that is NOT represented by a Java object.  I can't find any documentation or other people having success with this, so here's what I want to be able to do:

```
@GET("/my/api/call")
void getStuff(@Body String myDynamicJson);
```

or

```
@GET("/my/api/call")
void getStuff(@Body JSONObject myDynamicJson);
```

But these pass into the marshaller that expects Java objects.  Wondering how I can accomplish this without going around Retrofit or hacking some pseudo-dynamic Java object with a custom deserializer (where I'm headed).  This is needed in order to handle a dynamic server-provided structure that the app dynamically interprets and then sends values back based on the dynamic parameters (which can be complex objects themselves, not just name:value pairs).

Comment: What you mean by ` NOT represented by a Java object.` ? That you are trying to send non native Json ?

Comment: Meaning I don't want to object-model the Json with Java objects, I want to be able to dynamically decide the structure.

Comment: Turns out my first option does actually work.  I had problems with this with possibly a previous library version or something so didn't think it worked.  Does with latest versions (at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the `@Body` annotation to take an object.

```
@Body Object body
```

You can then pass in a String, Java Object, etc and they will parse to json content.

```
String body = "testing"

Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 9
"testing"
```

or as an object

```
SampleClass body = new SampleClass(10, "hello")

Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 24
{"id":10,"name":"hello"}
```

or as a JSONObject

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
obj.addProperty("id", 10);
obj.addProperty("name", "hello");
body = obj;

Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 24
{"id":10,"name":"hello"}
```

Comment: The second one is what I do NOT want, since it would require me to define the object hierarchy in Java objects (I need it to be fully dynamic).  It looks like the using '@Body String body' actually works, but I swear I'd had problems doing this before (it was getting wrapped in extra braces or some such), but maybe that was a previous library version.  Wound up implementing a Java object that took some generic types for now that has a custom Serializer to format the subtypes as needed.  Not fully dynamic, but works for what I'm doing for now.  Will mark as accepted since the first option works

Comment: @ColinM. - this also works with a JSONObject created from scratch which is maybe what you were trying to achieve. Tried it and returned the same as the SampleClass output.